# Unable to update label in an asp.net WebForm which uses AjaxFileUpload control on Firefox browser

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, getelementbyid

I am using [AjaxFileUpload control](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx) on an ASP.net web form. On the `OnClientUploadComplete` event, I am updating a label using

`document.getEleemntById("<%=TestLabel.ClientId%>").innerText="someText"`

This works fine in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer (lable updates fine after upload is complete). However, in Firefox , the debugger shows element not found error right at the document.getElementID.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload" 
                 OnUploadComplete="UploadComplete" 
                 runat="server" OnClientUploadComplete="UploadCompleteClient" OnClientUploadStart="UploadStartClient" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" /> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function UploadStartClient() {

        }
        function UploadCompleteClient(sender, args) {
          //alert("upload complete");
          document.getElementById("TestLabel").innerText = "test text";

        }


       </script>
```

The above is a snippet of my code. Based on some of the answers on stack overflow,

- I tried placing the java script at the end of the page
- and surrounding the script by $(document).ready(function(){}.

But these approaches did not work as the label is not updated after the upload completes. I vaguely understand that this is because of how page elements are handled differently in Firefox as compared to that in Chrome or IE. Please suggest where I am going wrong with this and how I can get the label to update

**edit**
This is my aspx page

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID = "Mainform">
     <form id="Form1" runat="server" style="border-style: hidden; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; width: 717px; height: 606px; ">
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <p>
            Upload:
        </p>
        <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload" OnUploadComplete="ProcessUpload" runat="server" OnClientUploadComplete="UploadCompleteClient" OnClientUploadStart="UploadStartClient" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" />
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>

        <label id="TestLabel"></label>&nbsp

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function UploadStartClient() {

            }
            function UploadCompleteClient(sender, args) {
                //alert("upload complete");
                document.getElementById("<%=TestLabel.ClientID%>").text = "test Message";

            }

   </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Probably just a typo on your question and not the actual code but you have: ("%=label1.ClientId%>").... shouldnt this be: ("<%=label1.ClientId%>")?

Comment: Can you post your ASPX markup? In your code you have TestLabel but in the question you have label1... which is it? And why are you not doing ("<%=TestLabel .ClientId%>")?

Comment: Sorry , it was just a minimal test case. I did use TestLabel. I updated the question now

Comment: Can you post your ASPX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **ASPX:**

```
<asp:Label ID="TestLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

### **JavaScript:**

```
function UploadCompleteClient(sender, args) 
{      
    $('#<%= TestLabel.ClientID %>').html('someText');
}
```

Comment: Wow! works with .html . Don't know how this is different but this works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
function UploadCompleteClient(sender, args) {
          //alert("upload complete");
          document.getElementById("TestLabel").innerText = "test text";

        }
```

change to

```
function UploadCompleteClient(sender, args) {
          //alert("upload complete");
          document.getElementById("TestLabel").innerHTML = "test text";

        }
```